# rsync script not working

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a external USB drive that I use for backups. I wrote a bash script for rsync and it's worked flawlessly before. Tonight, I set the USB to mount in fstab and now when I try to run the rsync script it doesn't work. However, if I copy and paste the command from my bash script into a terminal, it works.

UPDATE:

Here is the line in fstab for the USB drive.

```
UUID=E89AF5299AF4F542 /media/username/drive_name ntfs defaults,users 0 0
```

Comment: can you past line in fstab for usb

Comment: I updated with the line in fstab.

Comment: make a test folder mkdir /usbmount and change UUID=E89AF5299AF4F542 /usbmount ntfs defaults,users 0 0 and try..in a nutshell avoid these kind of strings /media/username/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/ in fstab

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. Now, if I had another drive, could I use that same /usbmount directory, or would I want to create one for each new drive?

Comment: I have added previous comment as an answer.. yes.. you need separate folder for different drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a test folder such as usbmount under `/`:

`sudo mkdir /usbmount` 
and change

```
UUID=E89AF5299AF4F542 /usbmount ntfs defaults,users 0 0
```

and `sudo reboot` or     `sudo mount -a`

In a nutshell avoid these kind of strings such as `/media/username/f6c682f3-5271-4f2b-99e8-93aa3bd39990/` in `fstab` previously i had such a bad experience with such strings i.e [samba share not working under such strings](https://serverfault.com/questions/677065/samba-public-share-on-ubuntu-14-10-not-working-no-matter-what-i-try).